# Laravel MySQL working on local computer but not remote

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to deploy my Laravel (4.1) App and I am having an issue with it working correctly with MySQL.  I have narrowed it down to this line right here...

```
$curSessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('beginDate', '<', $curDate)->where('endDate', '>', $curDate)->get();
```

I tried changing this to the following and it returned as expected. (But too many records obviously)

```
$curSessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('beginDate', '<', $curDate)->get();
```

This does not work. It returns no errors and an empty array.

```
$curSessions = DB::table('sessions')->where('endDate', '>', $curDate)->get();
```

I then got it to echo the last statement it made (`DB::getQueryLog();`) and the query that it outputs works when I input it in the SQL box on phpMyAdmin.

To be clear. The Query log shows:

> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["query"]=> string(64) "select * from `sessions` where `beginDate` < ? and `endDate` > ?" ["bindings"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(8) "2014-1-3" [1]=> string(8) "2014-1-3" } ["time"]=> float(0.26) } }

And when I plug '2014-1-3' into the "?" it works.

The rub is... This works on my computer running MAMP, but not on the remote server. I checked the database structure to make sure that `endDate` and `beginDate` are both set as "Date," and they are.
Any idea?

Comment: Does the manually entered query work on the server?

Comment: Through the MYSQL query box in myphpadmin. Maybe of some use. I was playing with DB::raw and I think it may be how the pdo handles the dates? When neither of the dates are escaped with quotation marks the query fails. Is it possible that on my computer the MYSQL server is more lenient with a poorly formatted query than in my server at asmallorange?  Or better yet, how does the pdo actually format the string with the ? Syntax? Maybe I'm over thinking this.

Comment: I was thinking the same. However, it would be strange, since dates are bind as mere strings.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you try passing the string '2014-01-03' rather than '2014-1-3'? Are you passing in a PHP date object?

Comment: I got it!! I realized that in the date format I was using a date without leading zeros.  Thank you so much! If you want to add what you just said as a solution I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks, I just need a clarification: did you omit the zeros on both local and remote environments (i.e. same input, different behavior) or only on the remote server?

Comment: Ok - Here we go. Originally I was taking date(Y-n-j) as opposed to date(Y-m-d).  I believe what was happening is that when the date was being sent by the PDO, it was changing the date() object into a string and then sending the literal '2014-1-3'.  When mySQL was getting the literal string, it was comparing it to a date object from the database which was inserting the 0's. Since doing a string to string comparison, the month of one started with a 1 and the other started with a 0, it was automatically putting the month that started with a one later.

Comment: TL;DR - I think it's because I was using the date format without the zeros and comparing it to the mySQL DB when I should have been using a strict YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to be sure to include the leading 0s (as matpop suggested).

Answer (score 0):

First you should check that your table date type is equal to what you are querying.
For example if your table beginDate column is timestamp then your $curDate variable should be instance of timestamp. to do so you can do :

```
$curDate = Carbon::createFromDate("year", "month", "day");
```

Then you can use laravel built in eloquent like below :

```
$curSessions = Sessions::where('beginDate', '<', $curDate)
            ->where("endDate", ">", $curDate)->get();
```

FYI: there is another operator you can use for datetime period checking by using `whereBetween`, I'm putting an example here so you check if it does your job.

```
$curSessions = Sessions::whereBetween('beginDate', array($beginDate, $endDate))->first();
```